# Spring AMQP - Return Exception Message From RabbitListenerErrorHandler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I'm trying to handle exception with an implementation of RabbitListenerErrorHandler in my project which uses Spring AMQP.

Here is how I defined my consumer:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "inqueue", autoStartup = "true", concurrency = "3", returnExceptions = "true", errorHandler = "customRabbitListenerErrorHandler")
```

Here is my customRabbitListenerErrorHandler:

```
@Override
    public Object handleError(org.springframework.amqp.core.Message message, Message<?> message1, ListenerExecutionFailedException e) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return MessageBuilder.withBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myCustomData).getBytes()).andProperties(e.getFailedMessage().getMessageProperties()).build();
    }
```

My problem is that I can't deliver this exception message to consumer side. I'm getting this exception:

Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: Cannot determine ReplyTo message property value: Request message does not contain reply-to property, and no default response Exchange was set.

From this message I understood that there is no replyTo property in my messageProperties but I don't know how can get/found it. How can I send this exception message to consumer side?

Answer (score 0):

The error handler should not return a `org.springframework.amqp.core.Message message`, it should just return `myCustomData`.

However, that should not prevent finding the replyTo header; please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can see what's wrong.